# jQuery tr (table row) object can not be used twice/multiple times?

Tags: jquery, object, dynamic, html-table, row

See the comment in code for the question:

The tr object created dynamically with jQuery from JSON object cannot be used twice to append in different tables?

```
function myfunc(obj)
{
    //obj is JSON object

    jQuery('#ClientInfo').html('');
    jQuery('#clientListTable2G').html('');

    jQuery.each(obj, function( key, objClient ) {

        var tr = jQuery('<tr>').append(     
            jQuery('<td>').text(objClient.hostname),
            jQuery('<td>').text(objClient.mac),
            jQuery('<td>').text(objClient.rssi),
            jQuery('<td>').text("Wifi 2.4G"),
            jQuery('<td>').text(objClient.ip)            
        ).appendTo('#ClientInfo');


        /* HERE IS THE QUESTION */
        //If i uncomment below line than the #ClientInfo becomes blank and the tr row fills in #clientListTable2G only

        //jQuery('#clientListTable2G').append(jQuery(tr));
    });
}
```

Comment: where is the closing tr ???

Comment: I am not sure if closing tags are must required in this syntax. but working if appending only in one table.

Comment: Duplicate of [jQuery .appendTo or more general for loop not working as expected](/q/5529091/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**`clone()`**](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) because when you create an object and append to any element, the variable is still pointing to the inserted items. So when you use append it will only move the elements. Using clone the a copy of the elements are created and then we can insert them as normal.

```
jQuery.each(obj, function( key, objClient ) {
    var tr = jQuery('<tr>').append(     
        jQuery('<td>').text(objClient.hostname),
        jQuery('<td>').text(objClient.mac),
        jQuery('<td>').text(objClient.rssi),
        jQuery('<td>').text("Wifi 2.4G"),
        jQuery('<td>').text(objClient.ip)            
    );
    tr.appendTo('#ClientInfo');
    tr.clone().appendTo('#clientListTable2G');
});
```

Comment: This Works, but can you explain the reason in detail please?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a jQuery object and then trying to append at one place and using same object at another place. When you append jQuery object to any other element, it will be removed from its current place and will get added to new.

You must create a html string and then create jQuery object or append string directly. See below code

```
function myfunc(obj)
{
    //obj is JSON object

    jQuery('#ClientInfo').html('');
    jQuery('#clientListTable2G').html('');

    jQuery.each(obj, function( key, objClient ) {

         var tr = '<tr><td>'+ objClient.hostname+'</td><td>'
                  + objClient.mac+'</td><td>'+ objClient.rssi 
                  + '</td><td>'+"Wifi 2.4G"+'</td><td>'
                 +objClient.ip +'</td></tr>';
         $('#ClientInfo').append(tr);


        /* HERE IS THE QUESTION */
        //If i uncomment below line than the #ClientInfo becomes blank and the tr row fills in #clientListTable2G only

        $('#clientListTable2G').append(tr);
    });
}
```